# Tricky Full house question

Tags: full-house

I have 7 pockets, 
my opponent has 5 & J

Table opened with 7, 5,5, J, 8 In poker.

We both have full house.
Who won ?

Comment: Full house ranking prioritize the three of a kind first.

Comment: Not tricky at all. Sevens full beats fives full.

Answer (score 1):

Your best hand is 77755.  Your opponent's best hand is 555JJ.  Sevens beat fives, so you won.